# Usage of command variable in Kubernetes Pod object

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, docker-desktop

I'm trying to understand what is the correct usage of command in Pods. Taking below example of my yaml. This is a working YAML. My doubts are

1> the sleep command is issued for 3600 seconds, but my pod busybox2 is still running after few hours when I see pods via 'k get pods'. My current understanding is, the sleep should execute for 3600 seconds and the pod is supposed to die out after that, as there is no process running my Pod (like httpd, nginx etc). Not sure why this is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox2
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busy
    image: busybox
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
```

2> When checked on k8s docs, the usage shows a different way to write it. I understand that cmd and the args are separate things.. but can I not simply use both ways for all scenarios? like writing command: ["sleep", "3600"] as first example, and `command: - printenv \ - HOSTNAME` as another way to write second yaml command section. Can someone elaborate a bit.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: command-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-command
spec:
  containers:
  - name: command-demo-container
    image: debian
    command: ["printenv"]
    args: ["HOSTNAME", "KUBERNETES_PORT"]
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`...but my pod busybox2 is still running after few hours...`

This is because the default value for `restartPolicy` is `Always`. Means after an hour, your pod actually restarted.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox2
  namespace: default
spec:
  restartPolicy: OnFailure  # <-- Add this line and it will enter "Completed" status.
  containers:
  - name: busy
    image: busybox
    command:
      - sleep
      - "10"  # <-- 10 seconds will do to see the effect.
```

See [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#notes) for how K8s treats entrypoint, command, args and CMD.

Comment: Thanks, it clears up the first part (restartPolicy: Always)! On the second question.. I read the link about how k8s treats the inputs. A bit unclear on is there a right/better of defining commands and args, or both ways (from my ex1 and ex2) are fine? The ex1 is hardcoded values, whereas in ex2, as I read from docs, the arg can be variables as well. Is that all or there are other ways/uses?

Comment: "Better" typically means "clarity", in this sense always place executable at `command` and the parameters that it takes at `args`.

Answer (score 0):

For your second point, if you are not familiar with Docker `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`, I suggest you read the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) about them because it is directly related to Kubernetes's `command` and `args`.

In fact they are so related that they actually are the [same thing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#notes). That means `command` should be used to set the "core" of the command while `args`, as the name suggests, should be used for its arguments. In your case it can look like:

```
command: ["sleep"]
args: ["3600"]
```

Now for the first point, it is because a [Pod](https://kubernetes.io/fr/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/) is not a [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/), so it will continue to run unless there is a fatal error, the [liveness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) fails or you delete it manually.